# iPhone: Override UIButton buttonWithType to return subclass

Tags: iphone, uibutton, subclass

I want to be able to create a UIButton with an oversized responsive area.  I know that one way to do that is to override the hitTest method in a subclass, but how do I instantiate my custom button object in the first place?

```
[OversizedButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

doesn't work out of the box because buttonWithType returns a UIButton, not an OversizedButton.

So it seems like I need to override the buttonWithType method as well.  Does anyone know how to do this?

```
@implementation OversizedButton

+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
{
   // Construct and return an OversizedButton rather than a UIButton
   // Needs to handle special types such as UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure
   // I NEED TO KNOW HOW TO DO THIS PART
}

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   // Return results if touch event was in oversized region
   // I ALREADY KNOW HOW TO DO THIS PART
}

@end
```

Alternatively, maybe I could create the button using alloc/initWithFrame. But the buttonType property is readonly, so how do you create the custom button types?

Note: I know there are other ways to do this, such as having an invisible button behind the visible one.  I don't care for that approach and would prefer to avoid it.  Any help on the approach described above would be very helpful.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`UIButton buttonWithType:` returns a `UIButton` or a `UIRoundedRectButton`, depending on the value of the `type` parameter.

As `UIButton` doesn't provide an `initWithType:` method, I believe it would be dangerous to try and override `buttonWithType:`.

I suggest you subclass `UIControl` instead. You can then add a button as a subview to your control, and intercept `hitTest:withEvent:`.

Comment: I'm experimenting with that because it does appear the other is not practical.  It seems terribly inelegant though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it:

```
+ (instancetype)customButtonWithCustomArgument:(id)customValue {
    XYZCustomButtom *customButton = [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    customButton.customProperty = customValue;
    [customButton customFunctionality];
    return customButton;
}
```

Works also with other types, `UIButtonTypeSystem` is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The `buttonType` property is not used anywhere in UIKit, and in your code you could always check `-isKindOfClass:`, so overwriting `+buttonWithType:` for this property is rather pointless IMO. Just use

```
return [[[OversizedButton alloc] initWithFrame:...] autorelease];
```

(You can override the button type with the undocumented method `_setButtonType:`.)

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that I use an undocumented method in a commercial application that would require Apple approval?

Comment: @Ama: I suggest you don't bother with the `buttonType` property. But if you must, the only way to change it is via undocumented methods.

Comment: Well, I need to display UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure buttons, so "not bothering" won't work.  Should I assume that to your knowledge there is no way to override the buttonWithType method?  Thanks