# unrecognized selector sent to instance when assign a string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uibutton, subclass

I have a custom button which I want to assign a string and then pass the button as a parameter in a @selector. For this reason, in the header files CustomButton  I put a property "name". However, when I assign the string to button, I get this error.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setName:]: unrecognized selector sent 
to instance 0x8484560'
```

What does it mean?

The code in CustomButton.h:

```
 @interface CustomButton : UIButton

 @property (nonatomic, strong)NSString * name;

 @end
```

The code in CustomButton.m:

```
 @synthesize name;
```

In MapViewController.m

```
CustomButton *rightButton = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

NSLog(@"The button is %@", rightButton);
/*The button is <UIButton: 0x8484560; frame = (0 0; 18 19); opaque = NO; layer = 
  <CALayer: 0x8484670>>*/

rightButton.name = self.nameTable; //the error is here
```

Comment: as you see in the output of ``NSLog`` ``buttonWithType`` is returning you an ``UIButton`` instance, not a ``CustomButton``, that's why you get the error. Accordingly to this other question you will have to make something different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562713/iphone-override-uibutton-buttonwithtype-to-return-subclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button type to `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

```
CustomButton *rightButton = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Comment: @ConicaDegenere: with pleasure

Answer (score 2):

So, I have a similar "Custom Button", and it seems to work fine:

```
CustomButton* btn = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setName:@"Road Runner"];
//OR 
btn.name = @"Road Runner";

NSLog(@"Custom button %@", btn);
/*
OUTPUT: <CustomButton: 0x68283f0; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (0 0; 0 0); 
opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6828500>>
*/

NSLog(@"Button's name is %@", btn.name);
/* 
OUTPUT: Road Runner //the name that was set earlier
*/
```

So, check if you have correctly create the `CustomButton` class, because for you in the console, it's UIButton that is being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting the title? you have not posted the code for that. It has to be like this -

```
[rightButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", buttonTitle]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no setName :D
setTitle forState (as sriskar said)
or
button.titleLabel.text IIRC